# Running an SFTP Server on both Internet and LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, sftp

I'm now encountering an issue related to LAN and the Internet configurations.

First of all, my SFTP server is a virtual server, whose IP address is 192.168.132.128, running on Windows 10 through VMWare Workstation Pro. Its Ethernet card is virtual one and is NAT mode.

Secondly, my PC has a static IP address, for instance, 1.2.3.4, which allows me to connect it outside my house.

Thirdly, my PC also has a wi-fi adapter, and its IP is 192.168.0.186 obtained by wi-fi AP though DHCP.

So, I briefly describe my network and ideas, which are two parts.

PART 1, Establishing an SFTP connection from the Internet

Internet ---- 1.2.3.4 port 47777(PC) ----> Port forwarding to 192.168.132.128 port 22(SFTP server)----> Establish SFTP connection.

This part is done.

PART 2, Establishing an SFTP connection from the LAN

What I want to achieve is since My PC is included in the LAN through Wi-fi, I think it is possible that I can establish an SFTP connection through wi-fi, which means establishing the connection from other clients connecting to the same wi-fi. The reason behind this thought results from the fact that the transmit bandwidth is much larger through LAN than the Internet.

Other clients in the LAN ---- 192.168.0.186 port 47777 ----> "Do the trick" ----> forwarding to 192.168.132.128 port 22(SFTP server)----> Establish SFTP connection

"Do the trick" is my problem.

Update:

I think the primary problem currently is I cannot even ping my PC at 192.168.0.186 from other clients in the same LAN.

Network Schema:
[My network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3Ivp.png)

Comment: Ensure that the whole LAN is using IPs of `192.168.132.X` and sftp to `192.168.132.128:22`.

Comment: Sorry, I can’t get it.

Comment: The address of 192.168.132.128 is in a different LAN segment than 192.168.0.X, so you have problems crossing segments. Put all the computers on one segment so they can communicate freely.

Comment: I get your point, but I think it wouldn’t work since those dynamic IPs are under two different NAT networks, or there is something I misunderstand. Any ideas?

Comment: You might add to the post the schema of your network, because as it is I fail to see where are the two NAT networks.

Comment: Ok thx, I will work on it.